# Entity Framework - Lazy Loading Self Referencing Collections

Tags: c#, .net, database, entity-framework

**Problem:** I'm able to save to a self referencing collection but Entity Framework does not show them in the collection after saving to the database.

[image: Query on Feat with ID of 22]

[image: Feat with ID of 22 in many-to-many table generated by EF]

[image: Feat ID 22 with nothing associated with it]

**Desired:** Access entities in the collection by `{entity}.{collection}.{query()};`

**Entity:**

```
class Feat
{
    public Feat()
    {
        PrerequisiteFeats = new HashSet<Feat>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    // Other properties here
    public virtual ICollection<Feat> PrerequisiteFeats { get; set; }
}
```

**Context:**

```
class PathfinderContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Feat> Feats { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Feat>()
                    .HasMany(feat => feat.PrerequisiteFeats)
                    .WithMany()
                    .Map(m =>
                    {
                        m.MapLeftKey("FeatId");
                        m.MapRightKey("PrerequisiteFeatId");
                        m.ToTable("PrerequisiteFeats");
                    });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

feats.Include("PrerequisiteFeats").SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == 2)

This will basically query both Feats and Prerequisite Feats in the same query. It's combining 2 seperate queries into one.